# Convert 16-digit datetime string to datetime with microseconds

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I am trying to convert a 16-digit datetime string (with milliseconds) in SQL Server to an actual datetime along with the milliseconds. An example would be changing a record like this, `2022020804180454`, to read a US DateTime of `02/08/2022 04:18:04.54`.

How do I go about doing this? Google/Bing searches speak to having the date with a midnight timestamp

```
CONVERT(datetime, CAST('2022020804180454' AS CHAR(8)), 101)
```

which is not what I am after.

Any help or being pointed in the right direction would be helpful.

Comment: @marc_s Thanks for cleaning that post up. WAY more readable now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the handy `DATETIMEFROMPARTS`:

```
DECLARE @s nvarchar(16) = '2022020804180454';


SELECT DATETIMEFROMPARTS(LEFT(@s,4), --year
                         SUBSTRING(@s,5,2), --month
                         SUBSTRING(@s,7,2), --day
                         SUBSTRING(@s,9,2), --hour
                         SUBSTRING(@s,11,2), --minute
                         SUBSTRING(@s,13,2), --second
                         SUBSTRING(@s,15,2)*10 --millisecond
                         )
```

Answer (score 0):

Inject the needed characters, with `STUFF`, and *then* convert:

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(datetime2(2),STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(V.YourDateString,15,0,'.'),13,0,':'),11,0,':'),9,0,' '))
FROM (VALUES('2022020804180454'))V(YourDateString);
```